# Puphpet/Vagrant box build failing - key does not exist

Tags: vagrant

I am a front end developer and rarely have to touch servers, but I need to use a Vagrant box for a project and I am having problems.

When trying to `vagrant up` on a box obtained from puphpet, I am getting this error:

````
```
Error: Key D39DC0E3 does not exist on hkp://pgp.mit.edu/
==> local: Notice: /Stage[main]/Rvm::System/Exec[system-rvm]: Dependency Gnupg_key[rvm_D39DC0E3] has failures: true
==> local: Notice: /Stage[main]/Puphpet_ruby/Exec[rvm rvmrc warning ignore all.rvmrcs]: Dependency Gnupg_key[rvm_D39DC0E3] has failures: true
==> local: 
==> local: Error: /Stage[main]/Rvm::Gnupg_key/Gnupg_key[rvm_D39DC0E3]/ensure: change from absent to present failed: Key D39DC0E3 does not exist on hkp://pgp.mit.edu/
==> local: Warning: /Stage[main]/Rvm::System/Exec[system-rvm]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
==> local: Warning: /Stage[main]/Puphpet_ruby/Exec[rvm rvmrc warning ignore all.rvmrcs]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
```
````

This means the `vagrant up` command ends with `The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. [...]`. I can actually use the box, but I am unable to successfully start Solr. When starting it, I get the message:

`which: no lsof in (/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin)
Started Solr server on port 8983 (pid=10498). Happy searching!`

I am unable to access `http://[hostname]:8983/solr/#` - it hangs for a long time, then fails to load.

I have tried this on 2 machines (both running OSX) and see the same issue. After raising the issue on GiHub with the makers of puphpet they reported that the config I am using ran successfully for them, but my issue remains unchanged.

My config: http://pastebin.com/21KYTP0T

Could this be a problem with my machine? I do not have a firewall enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Port 11371 (OpenPGP HTTP Keyserver) is probably blocked.

I had the same error, after opening the port on router it is ok now.

Comment: Any other reason? this failed on me once without any changes to the network, tried again 5 minutes later and it worked but just curious